# how to group a file into a dictionary without importing

Tags: python

I'm having to make a dictionary from a file that looks like this:

```
example = 

    'Computer science', random name, 17
    'Computer science', another name, 18
    'math', one name, 19
```

I want the majors to be keys but I'm having trouble grouping them this is what I've tried

```
dictionary = {}
for i in example_file:
     dictionary = {example[0]:{example[1] : example[2]}
```

the problem with this is that it does turn the lines into a dictionary but one by one instead of having the ones with the same key in one dictionary
this is what its returning:

```
{computer science; {random name: 17}}
{computer science: {another name: 18}}
{math{one name:19}}
```

this is how I want it to look

```
{computer science: {random name: 17, another name: 18}, math:{one name:19}}
```

how do I group these?

Comment: Could you please share your **full** code? What you've posted doesn't even work.

Comment: Where did the `example` variable even come from?

Comment: You're reassigning `dictionary` each time. You should be assigning or updating a dictionary key, not the whole dictionary.

Comment: Your desired result isn't a valid dictionary or set.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the dictionary elements, not assign the whole dictionary each time through the loop.

You can use `defaultdict(dict)` to automatically create the nested dictionaries as needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(dict)

for subject, name, score in example_file:
    dictionary[subject][name] = int(score)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty well known problem with an elegant solution, making use of dict's `setdefault()` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_setdefault.asp).

```
dictionary = {}
for example in example_file:
    names = dictionary.setdefault(example[0], {})
    names[example[1]] = example[2]
    
print(dictionary)
```

This code prints:

```
{'Computer science': {'random name': 17, 'another name': 18}, 'math': {'one name': 19}}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative code:
(but @hhimko 's solution is almost 50 times faster)

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None).sort_values(0).reset_index(drop=True)
result = dict()
major_holder = None
for index, row in tt.iterrows():
    if row.iloc[0] != major_holder:
        major_holder = row.iloc[0]
        result[major_holder] = dict()
        result[major_holder][row.iloc[1]] = row.iloc[2]
    else:
        result[major_holder][row.iloc[1]] = row.iloc[2]
print(result)
```